# using class Object in Java

Tags: java

#### about answers below, thanks a lot but it doesn't work, may be problem also with loop for in main?

hello everyone I have some problems in Java, I have those declarations:

```
Double first1 = 1.2;
Integer first2 = 1;

Object[] input = {first1, first2};
```

after I'm trying to call some function from this class:

```
public class Summer{
    public <Y> void sum(Y first){
        //do something
    }
}
```

but I receive an error:

```
The method sum(Y) in the type Summer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

can somebody explain please why and how can I make it right, thanks in advance

#### Edited, I have a lot of code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //arrays for input
        Integer[] intInput1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        Integer[] intInput2 = {-3, -2, -1, 0 , 1};
        Boolean[] boolInput = {false, false, false, false, false};
        String[] stringInput = {"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"};
        Character[] charInput = {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'};

        //arrays for output
        Double[] output1 = new Double[5];
        Boolean[] output2 = new Boolean[5];
        Integer[] output3 = new Integer[5];
        Integer[] output4 = new Integer[5];
        String[] output5 = new String[5];

        //declaring first element
        Double first1 = 1.2;
        Boolean first2 = false;
        Integer first3 = 1;
        Integer first4 = 2;
        String first5 = "mama";

        //for saving from repetition
        Object[] first = {first1, first2, first3, first4, first5};
        Object[] output = {output1, output2, output3, output4, output5};
        Object[] input = {intInput1, intInput2, boolInput, stringInput, charInput};
        Object[] foo = {new sumIntToReal(), new sumIntToBool(), new sumBoolToInt(),
                new sumStringToInt(), new sumCharToString()};

        Summer summing = new Summer();

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            summing.sum(input[j], first[j], foo[j], output[j]);

        }


    }//function main ends
}//class ends
```

#### sum

```
public class Summer{
    public <X,Y> Y[] sum(X[] inArr, Y first, SumFunction<Y,X> f, Y[] outArr){
        for(int i = 0; i < inArr.length; i++){
            outArr[i] = f.op(first, inArr[i]);
            first = outArr[i];
        }
        return outArr;
    }
}
```

#### error

```
The method sum(X[], Y, SumFunction<Y,X>, Y[]) in the type Summer is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object, Object)
```

Comment: @rookie: We need more code. There isn't any "action-statement" we can see.

Comment: @Martijn is correct. Basically there is nothing wrong with your code. We need to see the `sum()` invocation.

Comment: Your error message now does not make sense.  It looks like you simplified it for the original question, but it does not match what you would get with this code.

Comment: I cannot try it at the moment, but shouldn't you declare `input` and `output` as `Object[][]`?

Comment: +1 for `Summer`! (And because it is good question because of the Generics)

Comment: Sounds familiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096175/problem-in-generic-template-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declarations for first, output, input and foo are declared as `Object[]`. Therefore when you make the function call `summing.sum(input[j], first[j], foo[j], output[j]);` it thinks you are passing four `Objects`. However you're passing an `Object[]` for your input and output. Therefore your declarations should be

```
Object[][] input = {intInput1, intInput2, boolInput, stringInput, charInput};
Object[][] output = {output1, output2, output3, output4, output5};
```

That way, when you make the function call, it's passing an `Object[]` instead of just an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The first param of `sum` is an array of `X`  (or in code: `X[]`). But you are passing an `Object`, the compiler thinks. But we know `input` is an array of arrays. But the compiler doesn't know. So you have to make it clear for him by declaring `input` and `output` as a two-dimensional array:

```
Object[][] input = {intInput1, intInput2, boolInput, stringInput, charInput};
Object[][] output = {output1, output2, output3, output4, output5};
```